# Visual Studio Navigation Bar Object Drop Down does not work

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason the Object Drop Down Combo Box (The middle combo box on navigation bar) no longer works in Visual Studio. I recently installed the latest update, but the problem occurred after that.

(I have already looked at the Question regarding multiple monitors - the problem occurs regardless of what monitor I use)

I have tried a Visual Studio Repair
I have reset ALL VS settings
I have deleted the Local/Roaming folders
I have checked and un-checked the Navigation bar tool setting

Nothing works...

Symptom description -

Load a simple VB Form Project and add a textbox

In the center combo nav drop down, select the very first item (Form1 Events)

The far right combo does NOT fill with the events for that selection.

Or, in the code window, select some code in an object event like TextBox1_MouseUp -

The center nav combo dropdown WILL show the TextBox1 as the selection and the far right combo will display the events correctly.

Click on any other object in the center combo - nothing happens, no list of events is shown.

I am willing to do a complete uninstall and re-install, but it takes hours due to lousy internet connections in Japan, so this is my last hope for an answer before I waste an entire day...

Thanks.

Comment: I have also done all the standard system checks - sfc, dism, etc. - no errors found...

Comment: What does the leftmost drop down show? Does it say "Miscellaneous Files"?

Comment: The Left Most drop down has what I assume to be the Solution Name and no other items.

(I have a project with the same name as the Solution)

Comment: I ended up doing a full uninstall of Visual Studio, cleaned the temp folder and registry and re-installed package by package.

Problem is still there - click on the dropdown, (there is occasionally a brief "flash" of it actually selecting the item clicked), but then it reverts back to the very first entry, i.e. the current Form.

Note also, if I go into the code window for an object event like KeyPress, the middle combo does update to that object and the far right window contains its methods HOWEVER  if you then click on any item in the middle combo, it REVERTS to the LAST selection.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug -https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Version-16100-release-editor-problem/1432877

Comment: Oh wow, a lot of people hit that error! It was fixed here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/53893 and will be in 16.11.

Comment: Installing the Rosyln VISX DOES solve the problem...although it took about 2 hours to download and compile...

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed in v16.10.3